# How to reference named spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to use vlookup to compare the first 3-4 letters in a column of addresses in spreadsheet 1 in a file with the first 3-4 letters of addresses in spreadsheet 2 in the same file, then provide the name in column B of spreadsheet 2 if there is a match. Spreadsheet 1 is very large (160,000), but I only need to compare against 100-200 addresses in Spreadsheet 2 at a time.

I've pieced together a vlookup formula, but don't know how to reference where the data is in spreadsheet 1 (named "CityData"). Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

`=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,3)&"*",A$1:A$160000,1,FALSE)`

How do I reference that A$1:A$1600000 is in the CityData spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

`=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1,3)&"*",CityData!A$1:A$160000,1,FALSE)`

This will keep your wildcard match and look at the CityData sheet's cells for an exact match to that wildcard, but be mindful that the wildcard may still yield a non-exact match.

Comment: I think that's working, except when Column A in Spreadsheet 2 is blank. Is there a reason to keep the wildcard in, and if not, how do I modify? I've tried removing &"*" and &"*", but doesn't seem to be working. Thanks again!

Comment: That should be &"*"   and &"*",     for some reason the asterisk * isn't showing up.

Comment: If you're concerned that Col A will be blank and cause errors, you can just wrap it into an iferror formula.